Android how to stop boot logo from showing
I am working on building from source for a Pixel 8 device. I have two questions.

bootanimation.zip

I know I can change the bootanimation.zip file in /system/media/bootanimation.zip. I have done this using adb. But now I want to figure out how to get my bootanimation.zip in place when I build my ROM.
I followed these instructions to download the source on this page https://source.android.com/docs/setup/download
$ repo init --partial-clone -b main -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
$ repo sync -c -j8

When that completed I got the binaries for the pixel 8 from here https://developers.google.com/android/blobs-preview and then installed the self installing script
$ tar -xf ~/Downloads/google_devices-shiba-11828832-a4df4492.tgz
$ cd ~/bitfi/src/android
$ ~/tmp/extract-google_devices-shiba.sh
<scroll through the license and enter "I Accept" at the end>
vendor/
vendor/google_devices/
vendor/google_devices/shiba/
vendor/google_devices/shiba/COPYRIGHT
vendor/google_devices/shiba/device-partial.mk
vendor/google_devices/shiba/android-info.txt
vendor/google_devices/shiba/BoardConfigPartial.mk
vendor/google_devices/shiba/proprietary/
vendor/google_devices/shiba/proprietary/vendor_dlkm.img
vendor/google_devices/shiba/proprietary/BoardConfigVendor.mk
vendor/google_devices/shiba/proprietary/ShannonRcs.apk
vendor/google_devices/shiba/proprietary/com.shannon.rcsservice.xml
vendor/google_devices/shiba/proprietary/ShannonIms.apk
vendor/google_devices/shiba/proprietary/radio.img
vendor/google_devices/shiba/proprietary/vbmeta_vendor.img
vendor/google_devices/shiba/proprietary/com.shannon.imsservice.xml
vendor/google_devices/shiba/proprietary/vendor.img
vendor/google_devices/shiba/proprietary/lib64/
vendor/google_devices/shiba/proprietary/lib64/libmediaadaptor.so
vendor/google_devices/shiba/proprietary/bootloader.img
vendor/google_devices/shiba/proprietary/Android.mk
vendor/google_devices/shiba/proprietary/Android.bp
vendor/google_devices/shiba/proprietary/device-vendor.mk
vendor/google_devices/shiba/LICENSE

Files extracted successfully.

Now all the documents on how to install a bootanimation.zip file from ROM build say:
Now open device specific make file and add the following line:

PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
<path-to-your-bootanimation.zip>:system/media/bootanimation.zip


I think my problem is I don't know what my device specific Makefile is. I added the line to device/google/shusky/device-shiba.mk
# Bootanimation file
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
       bootanimations/mybootanimation.zip:system/media/bootanimation.zip

I then followed this pager to build the sources https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/building
$ source build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch aosp_shiba-trunk_staging-userdebug
$ m -j16

During the build I got the following error:
[ 98% 86/87] finishing legacy Make module parsing ...
FAILED: 
build/make/core/artifact_path_requirements.mk:31: warning:  device/google/shusky/aosp_shiba.mk produces files inside build/make/target/product/generic_system.mks artifact
 path requirement. 
Offending entries:
system/media/bootanimation.zip
In file included from build/make/core/main.mk:1123:
build/make/core/artifact_path_requirements.mk:31: error: Build failed.
21:08:24 ckati failed with: exit status 1


I commented the lines out and reran the make and it is merrily chugging along now and is 84% complete.
What is the correct Makefile to put the additional of PRODUCT_COPY_FILES rule ?

boot-logo

I was able to use adb to put my mybootanimantion.zip file into the current install at /system/media/bootaniumation. When I rebooted I did see my new animation Yay!.
But it also showed a colorful "Google" a little while before the animation started.
A. Is there a way to change the colorful Google ?
B. Is there a way to prevent the colorful Google from showing at all ?
I have been told that this is in the bootloader image that was part of the binaries that were copied down specifc to the pixel 8. Which means I would not be able to control that. But I kind of need to know for user if it is the case that  this isn't configurable. For the boss you know.
Found Solution to number 1
It turns out you need to identify that a file is eligible to be copied. This is done with the PRODUCT_ARTIFACT_PATH_REQUIREMENT_ALLOWED_LIST macro. So the following
change was made to device/google/shusky/device-shiba.mk
# Bootanimation file
# Allow system/media/bootanimation.zip to be changed
PRODUCT_ARTIFACT_PATH_REQUIREMENT_ALLOWED_LIST += \
        system/media/bootanimation.zip
# Now add it to the COPY LIST
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
        bootanimations/mybootanimation.zip:system/media/bootanimation.zip

With this change the build completed successfully.
I can verify that mybootanimation.zip made it:
$ file out/target/product/shiba/system.img
out/target/product/shiba/system.img: Linux rev 1.0 ext2 filesystem data, UUID=41f3b85a-5cfb-5984-adbf-e00325a46232 (extents) (large files) (huge files)
$ sudo mount -o ro,loop out/target/product/shiba/system.img /home/chrisk/mnt
$ cksum ~/mnt/system/media/bootanimation.zip
309525862 11722588 /home/chrisk/mnt/system/media/bootanimation.zip
$ cksum bootanimations/*zip
309525862 11722588 bootanimations/mybootanimation.zip

Still don't have an answer for #2 though.
